# Multiple lines not reading into one list item

Tags: c#, io, listbox, text-files, clipboard

For some reason when I read in clipboard data and write it to a file, read that file in and set it to a list after delineating it with ¢ it loads up my listbox just fine on the first load as in when my form first loads up. However I have the following trigger on a button click, it is for some reason splitting up multiple line sections into separate list items, which is not what I want and not what the same code does when the form first loads. It's a little frustrating as it's writing to the text file and everything the same way.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // until next comment this is the same as what I have run at the start of the 
        // program, it loads up multiple lines into one list item as it should
        string checkForDupe = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt");
        string checkResponses = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\testfile2.txt");
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText() && !checkForDupe.Contains(Clipboard.GetText()))
        {
            if (!checkResponses.Contains(Clipboard.GetText()))
            {
                var text = "\n" + Clipboard.GetText() + "¢";

                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt", text);
            }
        }
        //The following has no affect on the issue stated in my question I have tried with out it.
        string[] responseTags2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt");
        List<string> _responseTags2 = new List<string>(responseTags2);
        var count = _responseTags2.Count;
        // Perform a reverse tracking.
        for (var i = count - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            if (_responseTags2[i] == string.Empty) _responseTags2.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        // Keep only the unique list items.
        _responseTags2 = _responseTags2.Distinct().ToList();

        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        listBox1.DataSource = _responseTags2;
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
```

input example:
"This is multiple lines in 
a text file that is for testing
this application"

right output example (what I get when the same code is running at the start of the program before the form is loaded):
"This is multiple lines in 
a text file that is for testing
this application" ,

"This is ANOTHER multiple lines in 
a text file that is for testing
this application" ,

"This is a single line"

WRONG output (what I get when I run off the button click that eventual updates the UI):

"This is multiple lines in", 
"a text file that is for testing",
"this application"

Comment: What do you mean: `splitting up multiple line sections into separate list items`? Please give an example. And if during form load and button click you are using exact code, why not put the code into a method so the code is not in two places?

Comment: instead of adding "\n", consider using Environment.NewLine. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Comment: also, you might consider reading `Clipboard.GetText()` into a variable one time, and then only use that for your comparisons (there's a small chance that the clipboard text could change between calls)

Comment: @CodingYoshi What I mean is happening is when there is a new line, it is taking each new line in as a separate list item. It should only take in list items as any and all lines between ¢ EX: This is a multiple "\n here" line thing ¢ This is another "\n here" multi line thing in the txt file ¢ - this would place the multi line strings into ONE list item, however instead it breaks it by the "\n " or NewLine, either way I end up with a string split into an array in a way I don't want it to be

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me, but I think it's basically what you're doing, only slightly cleaned up (and I didn't use the second file since you're not using it in the example).

My suggestion would be to create a single method that does this operation, and then call that method from wherever you need it. This way you will ensure that you're doing the exact same thing in both (all) places.

**UPDATE**

I updated the method to save the clipboard text as-is, plus adding a `¢` character to the end, when saving to the file. Then, when reading the file the second time, first join all the lines with a space character, then split on the `¢` character, and use that list for your data source.

```
private const string DefaultSaveFile = @"C:\temp\testfile.txt";

private void CopyUniqueClipboardTextToFile(string filePath = null,
    bool updateListbox = true)
{
    // Use global default file if nothing was passed
    if (filePath == null) filePath = DefaultSaveFile;

    // Ensure our files exist
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) File.CreateText(filePath).Close();

    string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();

    // Update the file with any new clipboard text
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText() && !fileContents.Contains(clipboardText))
    {
        // Save the lines to our file, with a '¢' character at the end
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, $"{Environment.NewLine}{clipboardText}¢");
    }

    // Re-read the new file into a single string
    string entireFileAsOneLine = string.Join(" ", 
        File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Distinct().ToList());

    // Now split that string on the '¢' character
    string[] listItems = entireFileAsOneLine.Split('¢');

    // Update listbox if necessary
    if (updateListbox)
    {
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        listBox1.DataSource = listItems;
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopyUniqueClipboardTextToFile();
}
```

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. What I mean is happening is when there is a new line, it is taking each new line in as a separate list item. It should only take in list items as any and all lines between ¢                                              EX: This is a multiple "\n here" line thing  ¢ This is another "\n here" multi line thing in the txt file ¢ - this would place the multi line strings into ONE list item, however instead it breaks it by the "\n " or NewLine, either way I end up with a string split into an array in a way I don't want it to be.

Comment: So are you saying you want to get rid of line breaks in the Clipboard text and only split on the `¢` character?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the linebreaks(for formatting when pasting like a paragraph into an email), I know that File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt") is causing issues as I'm not actually delimiting the text I know where the error is, however, I'm having a rough time finding a solution as I can't do a stream reader after writing to the file because the 2nd time I try to write to the file it gives me an IO.IO error as the reader is still using the file even though it should have been finished reading it. I need to keep the line breaks, and only split by ¢

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I updated my method accordingly and added to the description above, under **UPDATE**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting multiple lines in your listbox because you are not breaking the text by `¢` but just reading them into lines. This is your code:

```
string[] responseTags2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt");
```

Do this instead. Read all the text:

```
var contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt");
```

Now split them using the character `¢`:

```
var lines = s.Split('¢');
```

Here is the final linq to remove any empties and return distinct items:

```
var lines = s.Split('¢')
          .Where(item => item != string.Empty)
          .Distinct()
          .ToList();
```

Then set `lines` to be the datasource:

```
listBox1.BeginUpdate();
listBox1.DataSource = lines;
listBox1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: I ended up just replacing \n and splitting a string, then adding \n again in place of the character that replaced it when setting the user's clipboard text

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is the following;

```
string responseTags2 = checkForDupe.Replace('\n', '╜');
```

I replaced new lines with a rarely used character, then split by ¢ to fill the list.

To replace the special character so that it would be formatted correctly again I just replaced it when setting the clipboard text with the \n again.

Comment: But now you will have that character in the result. Plus this is more of a hack or a workaround. I suggest using my solution. Other devs would not understand why you did that.

Comment: It's currently just a first version I'm working on alone I'll make improvements for now it's kind of a proof thing / test to show my boss (I'm not a dev by trade quite yet) I will definitely use something similar to your suggestion once I make a second pass I'll put it in as a to-do. Also I remove the character prior to converting to a list with a for loop currently. I know it's not the most efficient, but I'm still learning a lot. It's my first program past printing crap out to the console.